# Redirect all requests for one domain to another domain while maintaining all other parts of the url

Tags: nginx, laravel-forge

I have an existing site at foo.mysite.com. I need to move it to bar.mysite.com such that all urls are permanently redirected to their equivalent e.g.

```
foo.mysite.com => bar.mysite.com
foo.mysite.com/something/here => bar.mysite.com/something/here
foo.mysite.com/absolutely/anything/and/everything => bar.mysite.com/absolutely/anything/and/everything
```

How do I achieve this using *either* [Laravel Forge's redirect UI](https://forge.laravel.com/docs/1.0/sites/redirects.html) or a custom ngnix configuration?

Both sites also have SSL certificates, so are in fact `https://foo.mysite.com` and `https://bar.mysite.com`

Thanks.

Comment: Use `return 301 https://bar.mysite.com$request_uri;` directive at the `foo.mysite.com` server configuration block.

Comment: Thanks @IvanShatsky. So you're saying after the line `server_name foo.mysite bar.mysite;` I should add a new line `return 301 https://bar.mysite.com$request_uri;` ? Note that the two domains are aliases

Comment: Yes. You'll need at least two server blocks for both domains. Actually exact `return` directive placement within the server block doesn't matter since all the directives from the [`ngx_http_rewrite_module`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) are processed before the location selection mechanism took its place.